# How does qFuzzyCompare work in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

What is the difference between:

```
if( a == b )
```

and

```
if( qFuzzyCompare(a, b) )
```

given that the variables a and b are:

```
a = 1234.5678
b = 1234.5678
```

Note: I'm asking because I am having trouble comparing doubles in Qt and I want to understand how `qFuzzyCompare` works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qFuzzyCompare) for `qFuzzyCompare()` did not really explain why one would use this, but in general comparing floating point values is considered a bad practice because two seemingly identical floating point variables may be found to differ due to rounding errors. You may read more about this and other gotchas of floating point variables [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/).

When looking at source code for `qFuzzyCompare()` for double and float respectively as shipped with `Qt5.6.0` (Hold CTRL and click the function to see this in `QtCreator`), it can be inferred that *it tries to reduce the likelihood of inaccuracies to get in the way of an equality test*:

```
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR static inline bool qFuzzyCompare(double p1, double p2) Q_REQUIRED_RESULT Q_DECL_UNUSED;
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR static inline bool qFuzzyCompare(double p1, double p2)
{
    return (qAbs(p1 - p2) * 1000000000000. <= qMin(qAbs(p1), qAbs(p2)));
}

Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR static inline bool qFuzzyCompare(float p1, float p2) Q_REQUIRED_RESULT Q_DECL_UNUSED;
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR static inline bool qFuzzyCompare(float p1, float p2)
{
    return (qAbs(p1 - p2) * 100000.f <= qMin(qAbs(p1), qAbs(p2)));
}
```

Comment: It is not *a bad practice* it is completely wrong to compare floating point variables with just `==`

Comment: This function makes an assumption about epsilon value. What are the caveats of using Qt epsilon and not defining it by hand?

Comment: caveats I don't know, but using it means you will be using the same epsilon used by the rest of Qt which might save you from subtle errors arising from using different epsilons in intertwined calculations.

Comment: @ixSci it's not "completely wrong". The equality does have its use, albeit rarely. E.g. if you store a floating-point value somewhere and want to check that this exact floating-point value came back (e.g. in a serialization/deserialization cycle), `==` is the only appropriate tool.

Comment: @AlexanderShishenko the caveat is that, contrary to Lennart Rolland's comment, this won't save you from errors: it will instead bite you in the ass by errors of the kind "I was too lazy to think up a sensible value". Your epsilon should be taken similar to _engineering tolerance_. This tolerance depends on the units you're using (due to their influence on magnitude of numbers), and on the exact variable you're calculating (because different variables may have different precision requirements). A correct calculation will likely have several epsilons: one for each kind of variable to compare.

Answer (score 0):

In addition the the answer above that goes over why you generally don't want to compare floats with `==`, note that **`qFuzzyCompare` may still not do what you expect it to**:

```
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR static inline bool qFuzzyCompare(double p1, double p2)
{
    return (qAbs(p1 - p2) * 1000000000000. <= qMin(qAbs(p1), qAbs(p2)));
}
```

Notice how it compares the difference between `p1` and `p2` with the element of smallest magnitude. Generally it makes sense, because the notion of what's negligible depends on the scale of the numbers at hand. *But...*

The kicker is, **the following will evaluate to false**:

```
qFuzzyCompare(0.0, 1e-16) // false :/
```

The difference between those numbers, although minuscule (below the machine epsilon for doubles), is still bigger than 0.0; so the test will fail, even though one would reasonably expect it to pass.

This should be a general enough solution, if you can define a sensible `SMALL_VALUE`:

```
qFuzzyCompare(p1, p2) || qAbs(p1 - p2) < SMALL_VALUE
```