# How to compare double values limiting the decimal places?

Tags: c++, qt

**Qt** provides the `qFuzzyCompare` function to compare **doubles**, for example:

```
bool compare(double value1, double value2)
{
    return qFuzzyCompare(value1, value2);
}
```

If I try to compare the following values `387.109287103` and `387.109287101`, `qFuzzyCompare` will return `false`, what makes sense, since the values are not equal.

**How can I limit the decimal places to compare two double values?**

For example, limiting the decimal places to `6` the two values (`387.109287` and `387.109287`) will be equal.

I have implemented the following function to do that:

```
bool compare(double value1, double value2, quint8 precision)
{
    value1 = QString::number(value1, 'f', precision).toDouble();
    value2 = QString::number(value2, 'f', precision).toDouble();

    return qFuzzyCompare(value1, value2);
}
```

But I'm not sure if it is the best way to do that, since it convert the values to `QString` and then convert back to `double`.

---

Here is the full example:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtGlobal>

bool compare(double value1, double value2)
{
    return qFuzzyCompare(value1, value2);
}

bool compare(double value1, double value2, quint8 precision)
{
    value1 = QString::number(value1, 'f', precision).toDouble();
    value2 = QString::number(value2, 'f', precision).toDouble();

    return qFuzzyCompare(value1, value2);
}

int main()
{
    qDebug() << compare(387.109287103, 387.109287101);    // False
    qDebug() << compare(387.109287103, 387.109287101, 6); // True
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: I'm using Qt 5.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does qFuzzyCompare work in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105308/how-does-qfuzzycompare-work-in-qt)

Comment: multiply by `10^precision`, convert to `int` and then compare?

Comment: @cse I don't think it is duplicate. The other question is not related to limit the decimal places.

Comment: @KelvinS In provided answer it is mentioned that: Internally `Qt` use ` (qAbs(p1 - p2) * 1000000000000. <= qMin(qAbs(p1), qAbs(p2)));
`. So your query should be should be solved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The usual way to compare two floating point values is to subtract them from each other, get the absolute value of the result, and compare it to an *epsilon* value.

In your case it could be something like

```
bool compare(double value1, double value2, quint8 precision)
{
    return std::abs(value1 - value2) < std::pow(10, -precision);
}
```

For a precision of e.g. `6` then `std::pow(10, -precision)` should equal `0.000001` (this is the *epsilon*), and if the difference between the two values is smaller than that they are considered equal.

Comment: @rafix07 Usual arithmetic conversion leads to integer promotion, so the result will be an `int`.

Comment: This will return true (is equal) for e.g.: 5.12 and 5.11 compared to 2 decimal places. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will return true (is equal) for e.g.: 5.12 and 5.11 compared to 2 decimal places:

```
double value1 = 5.12;
double value2 = 5.11;
bool result = compare2(value1, value2, 2); // result will be true
```

This is because 5.12 - 5.11 equals to 0.01 but will be represented as 0.009999999999999787 in the floating point number.

I am using the following approach instead that works around this problem by doing an integer comparison:

```
bool compare(const double value1, const double value2, const int precision)
{
    int64_t magnitude = static_cast<int64_t>(std::pow(10, precision));
    int64_t intValue1 = static_cast<int64_t>(value1 * magnitude);
    int64_t intValue2 = static_cast<int64_t>(value2 * magnitude);
    return intValue1 == intValue2;
}
```